# Solution of a differential equation in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, quantum-mechanics

I was trying to find the s-wave scattering cross section due to a potential barrier $V_0>0$. For the solution near $r=0$. I have the DE,

$$\left[\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{d}{dr}-\frac{l(l+1)}{{\hbar}^2} -U_0+k^2\right]y=0$$ where
$U_0=\frac{2mV_0}{{\hbar}^2}$ and $k^2=\frac{2mE}{{\hbar}^2}$, $E$ and $V_0$ are constants. How do I solve this equation near $r=0$?

If $V_0<0$ then the solution is a spherical Bessel function.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: should write clearly the equation ...because you differentiate nothing ...and what is l ?

Comment: Should be $\frac{d^2 y}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{dy}{dr}-\frac{l(l+1)}{{\hbar}^2} -U_0+k^2=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't name the dependent variable, so I'll call it $\Phi$. Rewrite $\alpha^2 = k^2 - U_0 - l(l+1)/\hbar^2$ to obtain

$$ r^2 \frac{d^2\Phi}{dr^2} + 2r \frac{d\Phi}{dr} + \alpha^2r^2\Phi = 0 $$

Substitute $\rho = \alpha r$ we get

$$ \rho^2 \frac{d^2\Phi}{d\rho^2} + 2\rho \frac{d\Phi}{d\rho} + \rho^2\Phi = 0 $$

The solutions are [spherical Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn,_yn) of order $0$

$$ j_0(\rho) = \frac{\sin \rho}{\rho} $$
$$ y_0(\rho) = -\frac{\cos \rho}{\rho} $$

If $\alpha^2 < 0$ then the solutions are [modified spherical Bessel functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedSphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)
$$ i_0(\rho) = \frac{\sinh \rho}{\rho} $$
$$ k_0(\rho) = \frac{e^{-\rho}}{\rho} $$

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write the unknown in your equation. Let $y(r)$ be the unknown function.

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{dy}{dr}+\left(-l(l+1)/{\hbar}^2 -U_0+k^2\right)y=0$$
Why keeping so many constant parameters, which hides a very simple equation.

Let $\quad a=-l(l+1)/{\hbar}^2 -U_0+k^2$
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{dy}{dr}+ay=0$$
Change of function $\quad y(r)=\frac{u(r)}{r}\quad\to\quad y'=\frac{u'}{r}-\frac{u}{r^2}\quad\to\quad y''=\frac{u''}{r}-2\frac{u'}{r^2}+\frac{2u}{r^3}$
$$\left(\frac{u''}{r}-2\frac{u'}{r^2}\right)+\frac{2u}{r^3}+\frac{2}{r}\left(\frac{u'}{r}-\frac{u}{r^2}\right)+a\frac{u}{r}=0$$
$$\frac{d^2 u}{dr^2}+au=0$$
$$u(r)=c_1e^{\sqrt{-a}\:r}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-a}\:r}$$
If $a>0$ replace the exponentials by sinusoidal functions.
$$y(r)=\frac{1}{r}\left(c_1e^{\sqrt{-a}\:r}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-a}\:r} \right)$$
To have approximates for $r$ close to $0$, expend the exponential (or sinusoidal) functions into series.